# Erro em loop em controle de estoque

Tags: php, variáveis, while

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM cadastro ");
   while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $idrepete = $resultado['id'];
?>
#divId<echo idrepete; ?>{
width:100%;
}
<?php
   }
?>
```

Esta é a parte que funciona, agora é a parte que quero fazer:

```
<?php 


    if(isset($_POST['encerrar'])){

    $idpedidos1 = $pedido + 1;


        $contamais1 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO idpedido (idpedido) VALUES ($idpedidos1) ");  // até aqui tudo beleza 



        $pedidosestoque = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE productid = $pedido");
        while($pedidosresultestoque = mysql_fetch_array($pedidosestoque)){
            $productidestoque = $pedidosresultestoque['productid'];
            $nomeestoque = $pedidosresultestoque['nome'];


    $pedidos2estoque = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = $nome");
            while($pedidosresult2estoque = mysql_fetch_array($pedidos2estoque)){
                $nome2estoque = $pedidosresult2['nome'];
                $preco2estoque = $pedidosresult2['preco'];
                $estoqueid = $pedidosresult2estoque['id'];
                $estoquedisponivel2 = $pedidosresult2estoque['estoque'];


?>


<?php       
// Aqui é o que quero fazer, como no exemplo de css a #divId sempre recebe o id para ficar tipo #divId1, #divId2 etc, quero fazer o mesmo na variavel sql ali em baixo EXE
        $sql = mysql_query ("UPDATE produtos SET estoque = '$estoquedisponivelmenos' WHERE id=$estoqueid ");
    }
    }   
header("location:index.php");
}
```

Sempre que rodar o `while` atribuir um valor diferente para minha `$sql` para que o erro de balanço de estoque não aconteça. O que acontece é que só o último produto postado que recebe o balanço de estoque penso eu que é porque o último *loop* da `$sql` que conta no caso se o `id` termina em 3 só o produto de `id` 3 vai receber o balanço de estoque.

Comment: Tentei melhorar mas principalmente o último parágrafo é um texto incompreensível. Nem consegui melhor o título porque não dá para saber o real problema. Veja se consegue deixar o problema mais fácil de entender. Faça pontuação. Escreva o texto com cuidado. Pense que quem pode lhe ajudar não sabe do que se trata. Dê todos os detalhes de forma clara. Não deixe espaço para confusão. Se caprichar no texto, quem sabe até você entenda melhor o problema e consiga resolver sozinho.

Comment: De novo: [*se caprichar no texto,*](http://jotalog.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/patos-e-assistentes-do-house.html) [*quem sabe até você entenda melhor o problema*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=djG552fTNb8C&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=depura%C3%A7%C3%A3o+pato+borracha&source=bl&ots=ks_lcTBXLS&sig=QGQidNo51rEb67h3a6hPPL0J4tM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hE3dVKjtBOmCsQS4gILABg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=depura%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20pato%20borracha&f=false) [*e consiga resolver sozinho.*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1224)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara de Inicio você precisa estruturar mais seu algoritimo, programar controladores para você ter como saber quais dados e como eles estão se comportando em cada loop.

1 -  Acho que você precisa da uma estudada na biblioteca `PDO` que é muito melhor e mais seguro que `mysql_fetch_array`.

2 - se for usar da forma em que está, faça detalhes no código como:
 Após executar o primeiro select utilize a função, `@mysql_num_rows` para ter uma ideia do total de dados que estão armazenados.
 Faça Validações simples para você saber o que está acontecendo no algoritimo, ao invez de `while()` listando tudo faça apenas rodar no total que existe e não executar tudo que existir no SELECT.

3 - Seu ID nunca irá trocar por conta de você não incrementa-lo, de forma manual ou utilizando `mysql_fetch_assoc`, como não existe uma incrementação apenas o ultimo valor ou o primeiro depende de como o SGBD irá representar é que receberá esse processo de UPDATE que quer.

Comment: Obrigado ja consegui usando PDO vlw ai. mysql_num_rows realmente ajudou mas o PDO é mais poderoso vlw XD